# How do I change the font of the text inside the <p> body of the bootstrap class "text-center"?

Tags: html, css

I want the text inside the p header to be centered which is why I am using the text-center bootstrap class, but how would you change the font. Also, how do you edit the already made bootstrap classes in your own css file?

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="text-center">
                    Welcome to the website!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the HTML code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

make another css file and put it after the bootstrap link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap .css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
```

then overwrite the values that you want

```
.text-center{
font-family: "Lato";
}
```